# Amateur 3D Rendering Engine

Tags: java, graphics, rendering

I'm trying to make a 3D engine to make my final project for my java class.

I think that something is inherently wrong with my code. I've tried debugging it for at least a dozen hours now and still can't figure it out.

The link for my code is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ay4p8dd7na956iz/Renderer.java?dl=0), and the real rendering portion of my code is from line 147 to 211. If anyone is willing to hear my explanation and help me figure out what's going wrong, I'll follow up with an edit.

Also, I intend to keep this quite simple and do not wish to implement matrices or most current/standard techniques. Furthermore, I'd really like to not get flamed for making everything static because I'm really sure that nothing is being changed where it shouldn't be.

Comment: (+Close) pure debugging code questions are off-topic here. you should post relevant commented code here directly (usually the less code  the better), add text about what exactly is wrong (example,image ...)  add what you have tried to solve this what you think it may be wrong. No one will debug uncommented code without specifics for you ... We can guide you how to do it or spot obvious things but not in the full uncommented code ...

Comment: Yes, I figured that much. That's why I just asked if anyone was willing to do that. No one has said anything, so I'm assuming that no one would do it even if I did what you mentioned.

Comment: You are wrong. People here will help but you have to change the Question as I wrote. No one will help in current state.

Comment: How am I wrong? I just asked if anyone was willing. No one said anything. That's just rude to blatantly state "You are wrong". Everyone here with rep has a big head and this site is most of the time useless...

Comment: wrong with that: "that no one will help". You just need to rewrite the question and include what is necessary so it actually can be answered. The rules here have their reasons .. for example if you write the Question/Answer right then it will help others not just you (and also attract more (right) people to see/help). It is hard to grasp for a rookie here (I was no different and still make mistakes ...) so be patient For starters Title should be about problem (so it can be searched) Tags should be chosen careful because it filters in/out people, Be specific as much you can...